# верстка не слушается

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/a0byoj48/

```
.mc__persons {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 5px;
    max-width: 300px; /*этот кастыль приходится регулировать в зависимости от разрешения*/
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

без ограничения в ширине, в зависимости от наполнения блок '.mc__persons' растягивается и выталкивает кнопку редактирования за пределы экрана. Как сделать чтобы от наполнения он рос только до кнопки после чего начинал скроллился?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, рассчитывать ширину через `calc()`:

```
.mc__persons {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 5px;
    width: calc(100vw - 80px);
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```